# Angular CLI - How to share prototype functions across the application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, prototype, angular-cli

I need to have some global prototype functions on the string class. Eg.

```
string.prototype.trimWhiteSpaces = function () {
  return this.replace(/ +/g, '');
}
```

I am using Angular CLI and I want this function to be accessible to all strings across my Angular 4 app. I have added the code snippet to a file called `prototypes.js` and in the `.angular-cli.json` I loaded the file

```
  "scripts": [
      "assets/js/prototypes.js",
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
    ],
```

However, I keep getting the following error when I compile my project

> Property 'trimWhiteSpaces' does not exist on type 'string'.

How do I make such functions accessible throughout my application

Comment: Are these prototypes already in JS or do you want them to be TypeScript > JS compiled?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is TypeScript doesnt know about these type definitions.

---

### Quick Method

Provide definitions for each of the methods you're using

Open **typings.d.ts** and add the following:

```
interface String {
  trimWhiteSpaces: () => string;
}
```

You will have to provide definitions for **each** function you're consuming. While this is faster, it may be a good time to reevaluate `prototypes.js` and make it TypeScript friendly.

---

### Pro Method

Convert the Library to typescript and import/export functions as needed. This is more time consuming, but if you own the library it's something you're going to want to do eventually.

If you wanted to update the library and still use the prototype (which doesnt treeshake well) you would do something like this:

File: **string-prototypes.ts**

```
String.prototype.trimWhiteSpaces = trimWhiteSpaces;

interface String {
  trimWhiteSpaces: typeof trimWhiteSpaces;
}

function trimWhiteSpaces() {
  return this.split(' ').join('');
}
```

At the top of your `app.module.ts` import this file like so:

```
import './string-prototypes';
```

The second approach would be to structure your library like this, and import the functions as needed.

File: **string-helpers.ts**

```
export function trimWhiteSpaces(input: string) {
  return input.split(' ').join('');
}
```

In a component:

```
import { trimWhiteSpaces } from './string-helpers';
```

You loose the prototype augmentation this way, but it guarantees consumers of your library are only using what they need.

Comment: Pretty sneaky to have changed the implementation of the prototype as well :D

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: this.replace(/ +/g, ''); to this.split(' ').join('');

Comment: I re-ran the tests several times. It showed regex to be always faster :|

Comment: The results I was pulling from Chrome and IE11 had it regex winning, but the difference was slim. Running Edge or [FireFox](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1752170/32357254-81950fba-c011-11e7-8b27-cc74a31e5053.png) blows it out of the water. In the grand scheme unless your building a framework it doesn't matter.

Comment: Also, the 'quick method' is needed for the tests to identify the prototype function.

Comment: Update : The 'quick method' doesn't seem to resolve it. `TypeError: identifier.trimWhiteSpaces is not a function` when I run the tests.

Comment: Make sure youre importing your `prototypes.js` in `test.ts`

Comment: I want to import the prototype once for all tests to be able to access it. The test doesn't use the prototype function directly. It invokes the code that uses it.

Comment: I strumbled on this question and that way of trimming seemed odd to me. So I made a JsBench and I found out that `regex` is faster! (yes in my example I replace double spaces, but it's the same for stripping as well)
http://jsben.ch/d1QAm

Comment: Jasmine is not able to find these prototypes, I'm trying 'Quick Method' , is there any way to fix  this

Comment: I am trying to use this with Angular 12 and TypeScript 4.4.4 and get the following error: `is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property`. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply declare such interface as global in a separate file and export it so that typescript knows about it.

So your file e.g. prototypes.ts should look like this:

```
export {}; // Using the export, there is no need to import the file anywhere.

declare global {
    interface String {
        trimWhiteSpaces(): string;
    }

    interface Array<T> {
        isEmpty(): boolean;
        isNotEmpty(): boolean;
    }
}

if (!String.prototype.trimWhiteSpaces) {
    String.prototype.trimWhiteSpaces = function(): string {
        return this.replace(/ +/g, '');
    };
}

if (!Array.prototype.isEmpty) {
    Array.prototype.isEmpty = function <T>(): boolean {
        return this?.length === 0;
    };
}

if (!Array.prototype.isNotEmpty) {
    Array.prototype.isNotEmpty = function <T>(): boolean {
        return this?.length > 0;
    };
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I cant make it work without `import './prototypes';` in `main.ts` (angular 16 using standalone components). Also, there are two typos: missing `{` and `;` in your code (around `!String.prototype.trimWhiteSpaces`) but SO is telling me I have edit at least 6 more chars  Hovado jedno.

Comment: Even in version 16, I'm still using a module-based solution, so I can't confirm. Typos fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the urge to prototype some methods too

We're working on a project that uses thousands of classes and members, a large amount of these members are completely repetitive and could be shared among the components

after a few minutes searching I came across these solution
**Angular Global or Shared Modules**

#### Generally there's 2 ways to handle it

1. **You need to share a particular code among specific components, and not globally**

this would happen to any medium to large web application

[Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)  explained how to do so

2. **You need to share some code globally (which this is your case i guess)**

**Note that** This option is different than just any ordinary global module , we want to populate some prototype with our own functionality

[This Article](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Extending-Native-JavaScript-Prototypes-In-Angular/) Easily Shows how to populate prototypes for our own use inside an Angular App