# Angular CLI - Karma - Type Error - Prototype is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, prototype, karma-runner, angular-cli

I have added a prototype function to the `String` object as described in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47065916/1773900

The solution works fine for the solution except that the tests do not identify the prototype function defined and throws an error.

How do I make my custom type definition load before the Karma tests run?

Comment: Please, show the code of your "added prototype to function" and faling unit tests.

Comment: Please follow the hyperlink for the implementation. `TypeError: value.trimWhiteSpaces is not a function` is the error thrown as I run the tests

Comment: Ok, i see you have asked the previous question - but what is the code of your test ? Are importing the new definition there ?

Comment: The test invokes the code that uses the prototype definition. But since the app.module.ts is not loaded before the tests run, it doesn't identify where the function comes from. Need to figure out how to load the `prototypes.js` before tests are run.

Comment: I think it's an issue or an intended limitation in angular CLI. Have you check amongst their issues (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues) ?

Comment: As a quick and dirty fix, I think you can write someting like `import '/../assets/js/prototypes'` at the top of each of the '.spec.ts' files that are currently failing.

Comment: Yes. I did use that workaround to get things going. Was hoping for a cleaner way to do it. Seems like a pretty basic functionality for a popular framework like CLI