# Angular Karma testing prototype function

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

When I am trying to run ng test, I get an error that

> Property 'myFunction' does not exist on type 'FormArray'

And it is a property that was added to app.module.ts to make it global.

And it is a prototype to extend AbstractControl adding myFunction so it can be called on an AbstractControl objects. (done exactly like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47065916)

What I can do to make Karma acknowledge that it is used correctly or make it ignore it?

edit:
Full error:

> ERROR in app/modules/settings/components/some-folder/some-folder2/some-folder3/some-folder4/myComponent.component.ts:74:23 - error TS2339: Property 'myFunction' does not exist on type 'FormArray'.
>
> 74         myFormArray.addValidators([MyValidator(someList)]);

Comment: Please provide actual code that represents the error.

Comment: Can you share a failing test's code?

Comment: I added full error in the edit but it is basically the same as what was added before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running a test, the `app.module` isn't implicitly imported, so the code where you extend the prototype is not being ran.

So you either

- import the whole `app.module` in your `TestBed.configureTestingModule`, which is not a good practice because it will pull in all the dependencies,
- or create a testing module where you run the prototype extending code, and import only the necessary dependencies (eg. the forms' module (which contains the `FormArray`) and maybe some components or services)
- or just run a prototype extending code in the `beforeEach`, so by the time your tests hit the part where there are forms, the prototype is already extended

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    // just paste the prototype extending code here, something like the following
    AbstractControl.prototype.myFunction = () => {
        // ...
    }

    // or even better, if you extracted the function above to somewhere
    extendAbstractControl();
});`
```

Comment: Can you please collaborate more on "create a testing module where you run the prototype extending code"

Comment: And by "or just run a prototype extending code in the beforeEach, so by the time your tests hit the part where there are forms, the prototype is already extended" you mean just to paste my code in beforeEach? Because the prototype is not a component I could import

Comment: 1. Regarding the testing module, please read more at https://angular.io/guide/testing#angular-testbed
2. Exactly, or maybe extract that code to a util file, so you don't have to copy it everywhere, just import and invoke it.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. I understand now, and all of the options are working. Very good answer

Comment: And about the AppModule, you said it is bad idea, but what if I will add import to my shared module that is used anyway in every component and I need to import it in tests?

Comment: The problem with that is performance. Importing your normal modules in tests is actually needed if you are writing bigger, more integration test like tests, where you test maybe several components working together. But this requires that for every test case a testing module is inited, with all of the components and services and whatnot, which makes the tests slower. So if possible, only import the necessary things (add them to the testing module one by one, not their whole module), and maybe mock some of them.

Comment: I made a mistake, First option is working, but if you are not importing appModule, it does not work. It prints error anyway. I think the only way (if you don't want to import AppModule) is that you don't use prototype functions.

Comment: @Kaspazza clarified the 2nd point in my answer. Try not to import the whole app module, only the dependencies. Remove the app module, run the tests, and check in the error messages what is missing, and only add those specifically.